# Insert/Display Two-Page Word Object in Excel Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, embedded

I've trying to take a two-page `Word` doc and insert it into an `Excel 2010` worksheet. I'm not trying to link to the original document.

So far I've been able to insert the object, but it only displays the first page. To see the second page, I have to double-click on the object which then takes me into editing mode. Resizing the object does not work, no matter whether I'm in editing mode or in normal view.

I looked for documentation on this and found [this thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/32783-insert-two-page-word-document-into-worksheet.html), but there wasn't really a resolution. What I **don't** want to do is split up my document into two separate files, although it's looking more like that's my only option at this point.

Does anyone know how to display **both** pages of a `Word` document in an `Excel` worksheet without splitting them into two separate files? Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Another workaround is the height of the page - it works, but there is a limit of 55,87cm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the solution I settled on.

I embedded the Word document in the sheet. Since the user can scroll down the document when it's in edit mode, I used VBA to automatically put the object in edit mode:

```
'This code is called from a button on a different sheet. It could also be put in _
'a Worksheet_SheetActivate instead or called from a button on the same sheet. 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    .Activate
    .Shapes.Range(Array("Object 7")).Select
    Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This way, the user doesn't have to double-click the object to enter edit mode... this isn't the ideal solution, but it's a decent workaround for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Realize this is an older post, but adding my fix just in case it helps someone else. Piggy backing off of Hugo, you're able to create custom page sizes in Word. Go to Layout > Open Size menu (Page Setup window) > Click "More Paper Sizes..." From there you can change the size of the paper until it fits your x amount of pages onto one. It worked well to start with Letter size (8.5 width) then adjust the length until it included all of my text on one page. It worked real slick! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that *nearly* works.  You can create a text box in excel, and then select all text in the word document (Ctrl-A), copy it and paste it into the Excel text box.

Graphics and size formatting don't usually make it across the divide, but bold, links, so forth usually do.

Like I said, not a perfect solution, but if your word document is more text than formatting, you should get close.  It's the only way I've ever managed to get more than one Word page into Excel

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still hoping to embed the object into the sheet though. I'm surprised at the lack of functionality between Word and Excel...I'll keep working with it and see if I can figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by changing the page size in Word from A4 to a custom size (the largest length possible). This was then long enough that when I inserted into excel as an object it all appeared. My original file was close to two pages long.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by making the object the size of the first word doc page in excel by dragging the resize object dot at the bottom middle while the object was not yet opened. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem: got a two page Word document that no matter what will always come up as a single page into Excel.
So, I got inspired by the stars and changed the size of the Word document from A4 to A3 and then, boom, everything fit nicely. The font is a bit small, you always need to double click on the document's image to be able to work with it but at least I can see it completely. More a bandage than a real solution but it works...
Cheers