# Word embedded in Excel shows only the first page

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, embedding

I have this view of a Word file embedded in Excel:

[image: Word page embedded in Excel]

I intentionally made the height of the page of 10cm. There is plenty of space below the last line, but I cannot see the data which is actually on the other page of the Word file.

How can I see all the data in the embedded Word file?

I tried increasing the height of the page - it works, but there is a limit of 55,87cm. Is there any other option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert/Display Two-Page Word Object in Excel Sheet](http://superuser.com/questions/716631/insert-display-two-page-word-object-in-excel-sheet)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The question in its essence seems to be the same. However none of the 2 answers in the link really solves the problem, even the one which is accepted (answered by the asker).